# Why is derivative of a function at a point the slope of the tangent at that point?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, tangent-line, slope

Consider a function y = f(x). 
Let one point A on the curve be (a , f(a)) and a second point B (a+h , f(a+h)).
$m_{AB} = (f(a+h) - f(a))/ h$.
As h → 0 point A and B come closer.
My question is:
As points A and B come closer, why does the line joining them have to be a tangent? Since the points are so close can't it be a chord passing through A?
If we consider A and B as a single point, there are many lines passing through A.Then why a tangent?
Can anybody help?

Comment: It will help to draw this on paper with various values of $h$. But the basic idea is that withs limit you should never imagine that the two points are the same. The closest thing that you can imagine is that there are two points that are an infinitesimal distance apart (which is roughly how the inventors of calculus in the 1600s would have thought about it).

Comment: There isn't a more rigorous proof of the fact that the line would be a tangent? Although intuitively it feels that the line is a tangent, I don't know why it can't be a chord

Comment: If you want a rigorous proof, first you have to define what you mean by a tangent. Rigorously. Can you do that?

Comment: A tangent is a line that intersects the curve at exactly 1 point. Isn't this rigorous?

Comment: A line that crosses a smooth curve at some random angle can intersect the curve at exactly one point (e.g. $y=x^2$ and the $y$ axis.)

Comment: Your proposed definition is hopelessly wrong! For instance, consider the function $y=x$. A line that intersects the graph of this function is a tangent if and only if it is _not_ the case that it intersects the curve at exactly one point.

Comment: Yes, I got my mistake. What would the definition of a tangent be then?

Comment: You specifically asked for a _rigorous proof_ that the line would be a tangent. But you don't know what a tangent is! Perhaps you should start with [this Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tangent).

Comment: Now I understand. There is no rigorous geometric definition of a tangent for a general curve. We would need calculus to define a tangent rigorously. Geometrically a tangent is just a line that "just touches the curve" at that point. Using the calculus definition of a tangent we can get an idea of why a tangent just touches a curve. Am I right?

Comment: I think that puts it very well.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are right. The line $AB$ is a chord (or secant). Following up @sasquires comment, what you have to imagine is that there are two lines.

The first is the tangent at $A$. We are interested in finding its gradient, but we only have one point, so we cannot find it diectly.
The second line is the chord $AB$. We have two points so we can find its gradient.
Now imagine point $B$ moving closer to point $A$. The closer it gets, the closer its gradient gets to the gradient we are interested in (the gradient of the tangent at $A$). And if we make the distance between $A$ and $B$ infinitesimally small (but not zero), we can say that the gradient $AB$ is the same (almost) as the gradient of the tangent at $A$.
In fact, as $h$ approaches 0, the gradient $AB$ approaches the gradient of the tangent at $A$.